# How can I loop into two different DIVS without repeating in wordpress custom post

Tags: php, css, wordpress

this is  the code of my custom post.I am not so expert in php.So Please help me in this matter.

```html
<?php $featuresitems=new WP_Query(array( 'post_type'=>'scbleftfeatures' )); ?>

<?php while( $featuresitems->have_posts()) : $featuresitems->the_post(); ?>

<div class="col-md-6 left-grid">
  <div class="features-grid1">
    <div class="feature">
      <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="icon5">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail('features_icon_size'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6 right-grid">
  <div class="features-grid1">
    <div class="feature">
      <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
      <?php the_content(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="icon5">
      <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: why are you looping two divs like this? you obviously will repeat it makes no sense? your query isnt great either. Explain what you want the output to be.

Comment: I want that in post there will be two divs.odd posts will take place in left-grid and even posts will take place in right-grid div

Comment: right so this is defo the wrong way to go about it. I dont even understand why you would do that and not just use display:inline-block

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question is a little vague but I'm assuming what you *actually* want to do is just change the classes `left-grid` and `right-grid` for every second div. In that case you don't have to repeat the whole divs, just change the classes. This can done with help of a "counter" (`$i`).

```
<?php

$featuresitems = new WP_Query(array(
    'post_type' => 'scbleftfeatures'
));
$i = 0;

?>

<?php
while( $featuresitems->have_posts()) : $featuresitems->the_post();
    $i_is_even = ($i % 2 == 0);
    ?>

<div class="col-md-6 <?php if ($i_is_even) {echo 'left-grid'; } else { echo 'right-grid'; }; ?>">
    <div class="features-grid1">
        <div class="feature">
            <h4><?php the_title(); ?></h4>
            <?php the_content(); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="icon5">
            <?php the_post_thumbnail('features_icon_size'); ?>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
$i ++;
endwhile;
?>
```

If you're curious about the `%` operator I suggest you check out the Modulus operator on http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php

And if you actually want to alter between different divs you can put the whole divs inside the if/else blocks instead of just the classes.

---

Edit:
Not sure why you'd want this as it seems you're using the bootstrap grid anyways.

Comment: Thanks.It works.Actually I was wanting this simple things.